# Function dbReadTable in R package PostgreSQL can't handle encode specific sign

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8

I have a problem with encoding in R.

Code:

```
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv, host="host", port=port, user="user", dbname="dbname")

postgresqlpqExec(con, "SET client_encoding = 'windows-1250'")

# read tables and assign to variables
claims <- dbReadTable(con, c("schema","table_name"))
```

Error (after last command):

> Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
>     RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : BŁĄD:  znak sekwencją bajtów 0xe2 0x80 0x91 kodowany w "UTF8" nie ma równoważnego w kodowaniu "WIN1250"
>   )
>   Error in names(out) <- make.names(names(out), unique = TRUE) : 
>     attempt to set an attribute on NULL
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In postgresqlQuickSQL(conn, statement, ...) :
>     Could not create executeSELECT * from "schema"."table_name"

I checked the sign and it's similar to dash (see http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8064&names=-&utf8=0x):

> Unicode code point = U+2011;   character = ‑  ; UTF-8 (hex.) = 0xe2 0x80
>   0x91

I also tried to find in which lines the problem occurs. I found one row:

> mail // AC // Uszkodzenie pojazdu zaparkowanego przez osoby trzecie //
>   Nr szkody zew.: xxxx// użytkownik - Jan Kowalski -

Comment: Can you show an example piece of your data, please.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly what you want, but this might solve your problem. Try this:

```
myEncode=function(x){
  #you may want to change this to source encoding. 
  #For me its 'latin1'
  Encoding(x)="UTF-8" 
  return(x)
}

 myReadTable= function(db,tab){
  myTable = dbReadTable(db,tab)
  myTable=apply(myTable,2,myEncode)
  return(myTable)
}
```